# ffmpeg bash script to generate thumbnails for all videos in a folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I found this bash script via google and would like to modify it slightly to generate jpg thumbnails from a desktop folder call indie. All my mts files are named by their exact time taken and ffmpeg is installed.

This is the original script :

```
for f in *.mov; do
    ffmpeg -y -i "$f" -f image2 -ss 10 -vframes 1 -an "${f%.mov}.jpg";
done
```

I changed it to this :

```
for f in Desktop/indie/*.mts; do
    ffmpeg -y -i "$f" -f image2 -ss 10 -vframes 1 -an "${f%.mts}.jpg";
done
```

I am hoping someone can tell me where I have gone wrong (my terminal output just says no such file).

Thanks

Comment: then there's probably no such file. instead of ffmpeg, do echo "$f" and check if those files exist. That would be the first step in solving this

Comment: I could not get echo "$f" to respond - I know I am doing something wrong but do not know what - however Ls produced a list with indie listed

Comment: what is the output of: for f in Desktop/indie/*.mts; do echo $f; done ? (also, make sure to run this from your user's root directory)

Comment: lubuntu@lubuntu-HP-xw6400-Workstation:~$  f in Desktop/indie/*.mts
f: command not found
lubuntu@lubuntu-HP-xw6400-Workstation:~$  f in Desktop/indie/*.mts; do echo $f; donebash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
lubuntu@lubuntu-HP-xw6400-Workstation:~$

Comment: Tried again -  root@lubuntu-HP-xw6400-Workstation:~# for f in Desktop/indie/*.mts; do echo $f; done
Desktop/indie/*.mts
root@lubuntu-HP-xw6400-Workstation:~#